# return the for loop and child component React

Tags: reactjs, for-loop, return

The parent component App received from the child component an **Integer number**! In the parent component I will return the child component and the `<FaStar/>` inside the for loop. What should I do to see the start?
How can I return both of them?

```
import React from 'react'
import Form from "./Form";
import{FaStar} from "react-icons/fa"
// App parent Component 
function StarReviews(params) {
    const getData =(data)=>{
        console.log(data);
    }
    const data=data;
    for (let i = 0; i < data; i++) {
        return <FaStar/>
      }
    return (<Form getData={getData}/> 
);
}
export default StarReviews;
```

I tried to put them together and write only one return but it doesn't work!

Comment: Don't `return` in the for loop. This will cause the function to exit immediately. Instead, you need to create the child elements inside the form.

Comment: In order to give a more specific answer, I will need some more details. What exactly do you want the page to look like when this is finished?

Comment: could you please explain more what you mean ?

Comment: Why not do the normal React thing and `return data.map((i) => (<FaStar/>));`? Then again, the `getData` does nothing, and you set `data` to be `data` and `data` is not defined, so I don't see how this code does anything.

Comment: with getData={getData}  the parent component called the function and has recived for example Number 3  and i will do a for loop to show 3 stars the <FaStar/> is a star icon   , this number is always changing  and if i get 4 it should show 4 stars for example!

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? What should the page look like after this component renders?

Comment: if i  get number 3  it should show me  for example  ★★★

Comment: In short, you need to create an array with 3 `<FaStar/>` s. Then return that array inside a parent tag. A `<div>` will work as the parent tag, but there might be a better option.